Recompensa auto asignada. ¿Es posible revertirla para otorgar la totalidad de la recompensa? ¿No hay un plazo suplementario para otorgar recompensas?
En la pregunta ¿Cómo seguir el progreso de Android TTS en la barra de progreso de Media3 o en un control deslizante (Slider) de Jetpack Compose? ofrecí una recompensa de 500 puntos y hay una respuesta que aunque no resuelve del todo el problema planteado, me ayudó un montón a hacer funcionar el código y estoy en el punto de dar con una solución.
Debí haber otorgado la recompensa, pero entre una cosa y otra se me pasó. En preguntas anteriores con recompensa, si mal no recuerdo, cuando el tiempo expira, da todavía un plazo de 24 horas para asignar la recompensa. Pero hoy he recibido esta notificación:

Y cuando voy a la respuesta, encuentro con que a la misma se le asignó sólo la mitad del total de la recompensa, es decir, 250 puntos.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo revertir de algún modo esa auto-asignación, para otorgar el total de la recompensa al usuario que respondió? ¿Por qué se auto-asigna solamente la mitad y qué pasa con la otra mitad?
¿Estoy equivocado en cuanto a que se da un tiempo adicional para otorgar la recompensa, aún después de haber expirado?

Ahora te busco el post que explica todo eso por aca.. pero basicamente.. no a todo.. todo lo que es recompensas, salvo la asignacion manual, es totalmente automatico e irrevocable....

A. Cedano y no debería dar por aceptada la respuesta? Digo, al final si que le ayudó a solventar el problema...

Diría que la otra mitad se convierte en Cryptos, pero te estaría mintiendo. Supongo que irá al pozo de los puntos, que es un lugar al que sólo se puede acceder si pagas la cuota al barquero... En fin, mejor esperas el enlace de Gonzalo.

Me ha sucedido, si no asigno la recompensa, simplemente se pierde, el usuario que respondió al menos pudo obtener la mitad de la recompensa :-(
